# "Cannot invoke method repositories() on null object" when running gradle build

Tags: java, gradle

I was following the [quickstart guide for spring-shell](https://projects.spring.io/spring-shell/#quick-start) when I hit:

```
> Cannot invoke method repositories() on null object
```

My `build.gradle` copied their instructions exactly:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.shell:spring-shell-starter:2.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'
}repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot'
    }
}
```

How do I get my project to build?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After Googling to no avail, I tried combing over similar `gradle build` errors and realized they just seem to be syntax related.

I changed their example to the below:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.shell:spring-shell-starter:2.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'
}
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot'
    }
}
```

And my build succeeded.